# Ionic capacitor rest api call don't work in Android Sutdio's Emulator

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, cross-platform, capacitor

I just built an Ionic Angular App with rest api calls using Woocomerce's backend. In the browser i'm getting the list of my products, but in the android emulator my list is empty.
I'm using capacitor for the emulation.

Comment: Please open network console on devide emulator and try to check what is the problem seeing requests status.

Comment: what is you baseUrl http or https ??

Comment: Please post your code long with the description.